# Client gets disconnected from the server after sending data

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, java-io

I am creating a client-server remote screenshot capture application. I can successfully exchange screenshots between the server and the client. But the client gets disconnected from the server as soon as it captures and sends the screenshot to the server. I want the client to stay connected after capturing a screenshot. I am quite a newbie to java input/outout and also network programming. Can anyone help me by pointing out mistake?

Here is the complete code for client. If the code for the server is also required to solve this problem I will upload my server code also.

CLIENT

```
public class ScreenClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screen;
        Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 5494);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        s = bf.readLine();

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.contains("execute")) {
            Rectangle size = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

            screen = robot.createScreenCapture(size);

            int[] rgbData = new int[(int) (size.getWidth() * size.getHeight())];

            screen.getRGB(0, 0, (int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), rgbData, 0, (int) size.getWidth());

            OutputStream baseOut = server.getOutputStream();

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baseOut);

            out.writeObject(size);

            for (int x = 0; x < rgbData.length; x++) {

                out.writeInt(rgbData[x]);

            }

            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER

```
public class ScreenServer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    String uname;
    BufferedReader br;
    static JTextArea taMessages, taUserList;
    JTextField tfInput;
    static Socket client;//
    JButton btnCapture, btnExit, btnGetUsers;
    static ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList();
    PrintWriter os;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        BufferedImage screen;
        ScreenServer screenServer = new ScreenServer();
        screenServer.buildInterface();
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5494);
        while (true) {



            client = server.accept();
            users.add(client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            InetAddress inet1 = client.getInetAddress();

            broadcast(inet1.getHostName(), " Has connected!");



            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            Rectangle size = (Rectangle) in.readObject();

            int[] rgbData = new int[(int) (size.getWidth() * size.getHeight())];

            for (int x = 0; x < rgbData.length; x++) {

                rgbData[x] = in.readInt();

            }





            screen = new BufferedImage((int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            screen.setRGB(0, 0, (int) size.getWidth(), (int) size.getHeight(), rgbData, 0, (int) size.getWidth());
            InetAddress clientAddress = client.getInetAddress();
            String clientName = clientAddress.getHostName();
            String t = (new Date()).toString();
            ImageIO.write(screen, "png", new File(clientName + ".png"));
        }

    }

    public void buildInterface() {
        btnCapture = new JButton("Capture Screen");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnGetUsers = new JButton("Get Users");



        //chat area
        taMessages = new JTextArea();
        taMessages.setRows(10);
        taMessages.setColumns(50);
        taMessages.setEditable(false);
        //online users list
        taUserList = new JTextArea();
        taUserList.setRows(10);
        taUserList.setColumns(10);
        taUserList.setEditable(false);
        //top panel (chat area and online users list
        JScrollPane chatPanel = new JScrollPane(taMessages, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JScrollPane onlineUsersPanel = new JScrollPane(taUserList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel tp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        tp.add(chatPanel);
        tp.add(onlineUsersPanel);
        add(tp, "Center");
        //user input field
        tfInput = new JTextField(50);
        //buttom panel (input field, send and exit)
        JPanel bp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        bp.add(tfInput);
        bp.add(btnCapture);
        bp.add(btnExit);
        bp.add(btnGetUsers);

        add(bp, "South");
        btnCapture.addActionListener(this);
        tfInput.addActionListener(this);//allow user to press Enter key in order to send message
        btnExit.addActionListener(this);
        btnGetUsers.addActionListener(this);

        setSize(500, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        if (evt.getSource() == btnExit) {
            taMessages.setText(this.client + " has disconnected");
            users.remove(this.client);

            System.exit(0);
        } else if (tfInput.getText().contains("!getusers")) {
            taUserList.setText(" ");
            this.getUsersOnline();

        } else if (evt.getSource() == btnCapture) {
            MessagesThread mt=new MessagesThread(client);
           mt.start();
        }

        if (evt.getSource() == btnGetUsers) {
            taUserList.setText("");
            try {
                // putUserOnline(this.client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                getUsersOnline();
            } catch (NullPointerException nl) {
                System.out.println("ERROR--> No Client Connection Found");
            }
        }
    }

    private void getUsersOnline() {
        for (String s : users) {
            putUserOnline(s);
        }

    }

    public static void broadcast(String user, String message) {
        // send message to all connected users
        putMessage(user, message);

    }

    public static void putMessage(String uname, String msg) {
        taMessages.append(uname + ": " + msg + "\n");
    }

    public static void putUserOnline(String name) {
        taUserList.setText(name + ": " + "\n");
    }

    public class MessagesThread extends Thread {

        Socket client;

        public MessagesThread(Socket client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String ClientName = tfInput.getText();
            try {
                String response = "execute";
                if (users.contains(ClientName)) {

                    os = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    os.println(response);


                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ScreenServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the server's code.

Comment: @Inspired Sure! I am updating my question by attaching the server code. Its huge, so please don't criticize my coding style :P

Comment: From what I can see, the server performs new 'client = server.accept()' after it receives the screenshot. So, basically, the connection can be used only for a single screenshot. I am not sure why it breaks the connection though if no other client connects to the port.

Comment: @Inspired- So what can I do to make sure the server accepts other screenshots from the same client/other clients after receiving a screenshot. Lets say I want to connect to the client for fetching some other data from the client. What do I have to do for that?

Comment: You need to write a server that actually works.  Either thread off each client<>server comms loop for each client after accept() returns, or write an asynchronous server using one thread. A multithreaded server is easier to write but you will get invoved in inter-thread comms to signal the sceeenshots for display.